# PHP в Open server

Tags: php, html, openserver

Создал html файл, закинул его в папку своего сайта. HTML код в нем работал хорошо, PHP не работал никак. Вот такой фрагмент мой редактор (Brackets) показывает как цельный HTML код, игнорируя PHP.

```
<form action="" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="user" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['user']; ?>">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

На сайте тоже отображается как содержимое текстового инпута, а не как отдельный код. Я знаю что можно поменять разрешение файла на .php, но html часть в таком случае не работает. Как их слепить воедино?
Вот, не работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: поменять разрешение файла на .php, html часть при этом прекрасно работает.

Comment: Не работает, я только что сменил на .php

Comment: @Eternalblue Вам необходимо 1. Прописать в apache, nginx, или htaccess тот файл, который является запускаемым. Например, если это `php`, то и файл настроить на запуск `php`, а не `hmtl`. 2. Файл в разрешении `php` должен работать у Вас корректно. Скорее всего у Вас где-то есть дополнительная ошибка при построении документа - приложите разметку, чтобы можно было более детально сказать. 3. Необходимо убедиться, что и `php` установлен на сервере корректно.

Comment: Спасибо. Обновил вопрос, вот так это выглядит.

Comment: а зачем ты открываешь файл из папки? ты сервер сбе зачем настраивал? Чтобы сайт делать? Ну вот и открывай файл **на сайте**

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало